# IOS can't read QR code on iphone5 or 4s, but 6, 6s are OK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, qr-code

I put the QR code in an UIImageView and use the system method to read it.
It works on iPhone6 or 6s but can't read anything on iPhone5.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh }];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.QRImageView.image.CGImage]];
```

Comment: A useful thing to do to help people trying to answer your question is to describe what your code is currently doing and how that differs from what you want it to do. For example, are you getting any errors? Is the QR code read incorrectly? Sharing your testing and debugging outputs also helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you'll need to use `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`.

```
// Device
self.device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

// Input
self.input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.device error:nil]

// Output
self.output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[self.output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
self.output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];

// Session
self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[self.session addInput:self.input];
[self.session addOutput:self.output];
```

Other people have noted that `CIDetector` only works on the iPhone 5s and up, iPad Air and up.

(device reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20887)

Comment: Thanks! Your code works while scanning the QR code from the camera, then how to scan the QR code from an image in the UIImageView use AVFoundation?

Comment: If using a professional library is an option for you, consider trying the free evaluation of our LEADTOOLS SDK for OSX/iOS, which can read barcodes from both images and the camera. There's also a free demo on the App Store if you want to take a preview before downloading the entire toolkit: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/leadtools-barcode-scanner/id601172795?mt=8

Comment: @Veno If you are using the camera, then the metadata is added to the CMSampleBufferRef even for a still image. So, store metadata and use when necessary